# How would you stream output from a Process?

Tags: rust

I believe I understand, in general, one way of doing this:

- Create a `Command`
- Use `Stdio::piped()` to create a new pair of output streams
- Configure `command.stdout()`, and `command.stderr()`
- Spawn the process
- Create a new thread and pass the stderr and stdout to it <-- ???
- In the remote thread, continually poll for input and write it to the output stream.
- In the main thread, wait for the process to finish.

Does that sound right?

My two actual questions:

1. Is there an easier way that doesn't involve a 'read thread' per process?
2. If there isn't an easier way, `Read::read()` requires `&mut self`; how do you pass that into a remote thread?

Please provide **specific examples** of how to actually stream the output, not just generic advice about how to do it...

To be more specific, here's [the default example of using `spawn`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/process/struct.Child.html#examples):

```
use std::process::Command;

let mut child = Command::new("/bin/cat")
                        .arg("file.txt")
                        .spawn()
                        .expect("failed to execute child");

let ecode = child.wait()
                 .expect("failed to wait on child");

assert!(ecode.success());
```

How can the above example be changed to stream the output of child to the console, rather than just waiting for an exit code?

Comment: In general on SO, in order to give a starting point to the conversation, it's better for the OP (you) to provide as minimal a code sample exhibiting the issue, and then ask how to solve said issue. For example, you could probably switch your "one way of doing this" into a code sample.

Comment: I'll happily accept any example of spawning a long running process and streaming output to the console, by whatever means.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

> I'll happily accept any example of spawning a long running process and streaming output to the console, by whatever means.

It sounds like you want [`Stdio::inherit`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/process/struct.Stdio.html#method.inherit):

```
use std::process::{Command, Stdio};

fn main() {
    let mut cmd =
        Command::new("cat")
        .args(&["/usr/share/dict/web2"])
        .stdout(Stdio::inherit())
        .stderr(Stdio::inherit())
        .spawn()
        .unwrap();

    // It's streaming here

    let status = cmd.wait();
    println!("Exited with status {:?}", status);
}
```

Comment: Is this actually different from the default behaviour?

Comment: @msgmaxim You can check the [documentation for `Command::new`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/process/struct.Command.html#method.new) to see what the defaults are: *Inherit stdin/stdout/stderr for `spawn` or `status`, but create pipes for `output`*. TL;DR: No, I don't think so. Sometimes just being overly explicit or having the documentation read back to the OP is all it takes. Note the comments on the original question asking for a MCVE, trying to get OP to further explain the problem. ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: Saved me from losing more hours of my life on debugging. Thank you! This was the simples solution to how to stream stdout/stderr to console, as well as properly bubbling up the stdin questions to the user.

Answer (score 34):

Although the accepted answer is correct, it doesn't cover the non-trivial case.

To stream output and handle it manually, use `Stdio::piped()` and manually handle the `.stdout` property on the child returned from calling `spawn`, like this:

```
use std::process::{Command, Stdio};
use std::path::Path;
use std::io::{BufReader, BufRead};

pub fn exec_stream<P: AsRef<Path>>(binary: P, args: Vec<&'static str>) {
    let mut cmd = Command::new(binary.as_ref())
        .args(&args)
        .stdout(Stdio::piped())
        .spawn()
        .unwrap();

    {
        let stdout = cmd.stdout.as_mut().unwrap();
        let stdout_reader = BufReader::new(stdout);
        let stdout_lines = stdout_reader.lines();

        for line in stdout_lines {
            println!("Read: {:?}", line);
        }
    }

    cmd.wait().unwrap();
}

#[test]
fn test_long_running_process() {
    exec_stream("findstr", vec!("/s", "sql", "C:\\tmp\\*"));
}
```

See also [Merge child process stdout and stderr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41019780/merge-child-process-stdout-and-stderr) regarding catching the output from stderr and stdout simultaneously.

Comment: This answer is very useful! Quick question though: Any particular reason the stream reading part has been put in a separate scope?

Comment: @PascalPrecht to seperate the mutable borrows of `cmd`, first in `stdout` and second in `cmd.wait()`. Today the compiler would drop `stdout` automatically just before the `cmd.wait()` statement, but I think in the past this was not the case. So the scope here was needed to limit the lifetime of `stdout`.

Comment: @Doug what if the user needs to consider also stderr?